# Index is not used with same Query on two Servers

Tags: sql-server, performance, index

I have two notebooks with same specs (same model, only ram is 24GB/32GB, same ssd) and exact same database and same sql server version. SQLIO is 3300 and 3600.

Now I run a query on one notebook and get ~100 reads in the sql server profile and on the second notebook I get ~40000 reads for the same query.

I assume that the index is not used on the second notebook, even tho its there because its the same database (I restored it). The index usage report shows that the index is not used for the same query. The duration for the query therefore is ~100x higher.

[image: Notebook 1, index used]
[image: Notebook 2, no index usage]

How can I fix that?

**Update1 4/16/2014, 4:35pm:**

When I re-execute one of my 35.000 queries, the query plan shows me that the index is used. Still, I don't understand why the reads are 100x higher, this has of course, a performance impact.

[image: execution plan]

Comment: What's the execution plan? Have you tried clearing the plan cache?

Comment: The execution plan is the same - still the count of reads is massively different. Any ideas why?

Comment: Index usage stats are reset when the server is restarted, and includes *all* activity on the server. It's possible there was some other usage of these indexes besides the query you ran. Soooo many variables here...

Comment: How can the execution plan be the same if one uses a certain index and the other doesn't?

Comment: That is just my "intelligent guess" - I can't imagine why the reads are 100x higher with the same query and the same database. I reset all statistics right before I started the comparison - still reads and therefore the performance are very different.

Comment: Why are you guessing and not looking at the execution plan? You'll be able to see pretty quickly if it is/is not using the index...

Comment: Execution plan says that its using the index on both notebooks, at least when I re-execute one query. 
But why is there such a difference in the amount of reads?

Comment: If you look in the same screenshots, you'll see that the same index is used at one point with the Seek operator, in the other point with the Scan operator (which can explain the high number of reads). So the same index can be used, but not the same way. If you look in the plans, you'll have different operators for this index (Seek in one part, Scan in the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was sitting in front of the PC - once again.

It turned out that the query was not exactly similar, there was one where condition more in every query. We had different entity framework versions on the two notebooks that created different statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrow points to the #user seeks column for the clustered index in the report. The execution plan says it is doing a scan on the non clustered index. Are you expecting it to do a seek on the clustered?